# Laravel on Nginx: accessing to "public/" of the app results in "Permission denied" even though it has the same user as Nginx

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, centos

I've been trying to deploy a brand new Laravel 6 app on Nginx with CentOS 7, but I'm getting the following error messages on the error log.

```
*13 stat() "/ROOT_OF_APP/public/" failed (13: Permission denied), 
client: 127.0.0.1, server: HOST_NAME, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "HOST_NAME"

*13 stat() "/ROOT_OF_APP/public/" failed (13: Permission denied), 
client: 127.0.0.1, server: HOST_NAME, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "HOST_NAME"

*13 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream, 
client: 127.0.0.1, server: HOST_NAME, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "HOST_NAME"
```

The first line says `"/ROOT_OF_APP/public/" failed (13: Permission denied)`.

So, I ran `sudo chown -R nignx:nginx /ROOT_OF_APP/public/` and `sudo chmod -R 775 /ROOT_OF_APP/`, and made sure that the user and group of both Nginx and PHP-FPM are `nginx` (this will be explained below).

The question is:
***why can't nginx access "public" even though the owner/user is nginx ?***

(The 3rd message (`Primary script unknown`) also bothers me, but I don't know if this is to do with the permission issue)

In `/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf`, you see these lines.

```
user = nginx
group = nginx

listen.owner = nginx
listen.group = nginx
listen.mode = 0660
```

In `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`, you see the line.

```
user nginx;
```

(I'd like to note that the OS is **CentOS 7**, so it doesn't have `www-data` user/group, unlike **Ubuntu**.)

If I run `ps aux | grep php-fpm`...

```
user     24394  0.0  0.0 112708   988 pts/1    S+   14:28   0:00 grep --color=auto php-fpm
root     26979  0.0  0.0 306464 10520 ?        Ss   13:57   0:00 php-fpm: master process (/etc/php-fpm.conf)
nginx    26985  0.0  0.0 318712  5804 ?        S    13:57   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
nginx    26986  0.0  0.0 318712  5796 ?        S    13:57   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
nginx    26987  0.0  0.0 318712  5800 ?        S    13:57   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
nginx    26988  0.0  0.0 318712  5800 ?        S    13:57   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
nginx    26989  0.0  0.0 318712  5804 ?        S    13:57   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
```

If I ran `ps aux | grep nginx`...

```
root      2990  0.0  0.0 122420  5608 ?        Ss   14:01   0:00 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx
nginx    26985  0.0  0.0 318712  5804 ?        S    13:57   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
...
# The 2nd line is repeated several times
...
nginx    31299  0.0  0.0 134672  4212 ?        S    14:15   0:00 nginx: worker process
# This "nginx: worker process" is repeated several times too
```

I'm completely clueless... any advice will be appreciated.

***PS***

Here's how the config file looks like.

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/MY-APP-access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/MY-APP-error.log;

        root /ROOT_OF_APP/public;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        server_name HOST_NAME;

          location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
          }

          location ~* \.php$ {
              include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
              fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
              fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
              fastcgi_index index.php;
        }

        location = /favicon.ico { log_not_found off; access_log off; }
          location = /robots.txt  { log_not_found off; access_log off; }
}
```

`sudo nginx -t` shows that the syntax is ok.

Also, the `"SELinux enforcing"` status has been changed into "Permissive", so SELinux shouldn't be the cause of this issue.

Comment: Is root of app under/inside default www location?

Comment: try replacing `listen.mode = 0660` with  `listen.mode = 0770`

Comment: @ThanhTrung: Thanks for your comment. No, I made a directory called `app` under the user name, and all the apps are stored there. (i.e. the full path for this app is like `/home/user/app/my-laravel-app`)

Comment: @PavelLint: Thanks for the suggestion, but it didn't work, unfortunately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens to me when I tried putting my project outside /var/www>

I would suggest to put your project in /var/www/project_folder

then change your nginx configuration file as required then.

It will work.

Comment: Yeah, I also think putting under www is critical. Unless the config allow to lookup for path outside of www

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much! Honestly, I don't understand why it worked, because when I searched `nginx.conf` and `php-fpm.d/www.conf` for any string with `var/www`, it didn't hit anything. Also, (believe it or not,) I was able to put my apps outside of `var/www`. Any, thanl you so much!

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like it could be an SELinux issue, especially as others have pointed out, since you are in the non-default directory.

Is SELinux enforcing? (run "getenforce")

If that comes back "Enforcing" I'd bet that's the issue.

If so, you can disable it temporarily, restart your services, see if the issue goes away (run "setenforce 0")

Then, assuming you want SELinux on, (highly recommended to say the least) investigate the output of "ausearch -m AVC". Post back here for help.

Comment: Thank you for your advice! Actually, I've already change the "SELinux enforcing" status into "Permissive", so this shouldn't be the issue.

Comment: One other thought occurs, does the nginx user have "execute" permission on /ROOT_OF_APP? If you just ran the chown you mention, but the directory above is does not have +x for the nginx user, you could still get permission denied like that.

Comment: I ran `sudo chmod -R 775 my-app/`, so everyone should have the "execute permission". Still, accessing `public/` is denied :(

Comment: Hrm, it's hard to tell, as you seem to be using placeholders in your posts here, but if you have a directory structure like /a/b/c/public, the nginx user would need execute permissions on _all_ of /a/b/c/ or you could get read issues. Depending on exactly what the values of ROOT_OF_APP, my-app, etc are, it sounds to me like this could be your issue.

Comment: ^^ I just read your post above, how this is a subdirectory of a user's (who isn't the nginx user) home folder? Sounds like this is your issue. The home folder itself would be set 0700. If you want this to live under a home folder, the nginx and fpm process should run as that user.

Comment: I did setenforce to permissive by run "setenforce 0" command. then when I hit with the URL it goes to the login page with "404 not found nginx". before running this "setenforce 0" the url shows the permission denied for laravel log. How could it be solved?

Comment: @Faiyaj it sounds like you have more than one issue. I suggest you make a new question with more details about your setup. Barring that just double check the paths in your nginx/fastcgi config. I suspect they are your problem.